# Disable pre-run in Avast

Tags: avast

Some apps avast pre-runs them once for a few seconds (probably to check their behavior or whatever in a sandbox) before really running them. How do I disable this pre-step?

Comment: Remove avast ...

Comment: Are you implying that an antivirus these days is redundant, or do you recommend a better free and unintrusive alternative?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say Avast pre-runs some programs. Also Avast has been a poor AV product for some time, with plenty of both free and premium security products running more quickly and with better detection rates. Assuming you're running a relatively recent version of Windows, using Windows Defender will provide better protection for a lower system performance hit.

Comment: I'm running a new app. It runs for a few seconds as usual, then terminates, and starts running from the beginning all over again. I was looking for a silent antivirus that doesn't bother me. I can recall why, but win Defender annoyed me. But yes, maybe it's time I'll give something else a chance since Avast isn't unintrusive and silent anymore.